# Is it possible to control my IoT device from outside my private network using Google IoT Cloud services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

Is it possible to control my IoT device from outside of my private network through Google IoT Cloud services. Especially when my IoT devices are offline.

Comment: Can you be more precise ? Which Iot device, how is it connected today, how you can control it if it's offline?

Comment: You can consider the case of home automation and lets say my TV is a IoT device. Along with TV, I also have other devices like temperature sensors, AC etc...and all are connected to google cloud via a Gateway....Now I want to switch off my TV from mobile device and am out of my private network at home..... But through google could I want to switch off my TV...can google could have a virtualization of all IoT devices that I have at home...I hope it makes sense ... I am new to IoT and cloud

Comment: Is your gateway connected to internet? It's only your IoT devices which are on your private network ?

Comment: All devices are connected to gateway and gateway is connected to internet..

Comment: In precise, what I am asking is ... is there an alternative or similar service in google could iot just like Device Shadow service in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would set up a [IoT Core Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/gateways/) device in addition to registering regular devices.

Assuming you can program your gateway, it would communicate with Cloud IoT Core via [MQTT](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge)/[HTTP](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge). Then, you can use any protocol you want (zigbee, zwave, bluetooth, etc). The gateway device should be able to store private keys/sign JWTs which are used to [authenticate itself to IoT Core](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/device-security), so that the devices themselves don't need to.

For more information, I would read the following: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/gateways/

Comment: Hello Alex,

Thanks for your response. My question is not on how the gateways interact with Could. In precise, my question is, is there an alternative or similar service in google could iot just like Device Shadow service in AWS. If so how the device state are managed on the cloud.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, Cloud IoT Core does not have similar functionality for Device Shadows/Digital Twins. However, it is something that we are looking into. Nonetheless, you can accomplish most of what you described above with simple configuration updates + gateways. https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/devices#device_configuration